# Calling CryptCATCatalogInfoFromContext Throw errors

Tags: windows, vb.net, winapi, code-signing, sha1

I want to call the function **CryptCATCatalogInfoFromContext** available in **wintrust.dll**. But when I do that I receive an error saying **Specified array was not of the expected type.**
I am using the following code to invoke method. It seems some data type I'm using is mismatching with the required data type.

```
    'import wintrust.dll
    <DllImport("Wintrust.dll", PreserveSig:=True, SetLastError:=False)> _
    Private Shared Function CryptCATCatalogInfoFromContext(ByVal catalogContext As IntPtr, ByVal hash As CATALOG_INFO_, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    'create structure CATALOG_INFO
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
        Public Structure CATALOG_INFO_
        Public cbStruct As UInteger
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)> _
        Public wszCatalogFile() As Char 
    End Structure
```

I have already obtained CatalogContext.

```
        Dim infoStruct As New CATALOG_INFO_()
        infoStruct.cbStruct = 256
        Dim c(255) As Char
        infoStruct.wszCatalogFile = c
        CryptCATCatalogInfoFromContext(CatalogContext, infoStruct, 0)
```

the last line throws the error **Specified array was not of the expected type.**
Have I used a wrong data type for the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, wrong declaration.  It is not a SafeArray, it is a Unicode string.  The proper declaration is:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Structure CATALOG_INFO
    Public cbStruct As UInteger
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)> _
    Public wszCatalogFile As String
End Structure
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans. Your modofication fixed the problem. I also changed
Private Shared Function CryptCATCatalogInfoFromContext(ByVal catalogContext As IntPtr, ByVal hash As CATALOG_INFO_, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Boolean to 
Private Shared Function CryptCATCatalogInfoFromContext(ByVal catalogContext As IntPtr, ByRef hash As CATALOG_INFO_, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Boolean for everything to work properly.
Thanks a lot again.